# CUDA in Windows XP Embedded

Tags: windows, cuda, driver, windows-xp-embedded

I want to do CUDA programming in Windows XP Embedded OS with graphics card Quadro 600. The CUDA SDK i want to use is 4.0. I searched NVIDIA driver for Windows XP Embedded, but i didn't find it in the nvidia driver download site. Where do i get the nvidia driver for Windows XP Embedded OS.

How can I run the CUDA application in that machine.?

Please help..

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing the regular Windows XP driver from NVidia for your card? XP Embedded is just a componentized version of Windows XP, where you can leave out OS components that you aren't using. It's not a different kernel like Windows CE. As far as I know, it's just the normal XP kernel, so normal XP drivers should work, unless NVidia is doing something to prevent that. It's also possible, of course, that necessary components were left out of your Windows image by whoever built the XP Embedded image that you're using.